# how to filter the recycler view card view and show that card on top that is as 1st cardView based on some boolean flag?

Tags: android, sorting, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

how to sort/filter recycler view card view and show that card view on top of all card view in android.
I have some boolean flag as true on check of true I need to show that particular card on top as 1st card view then others below and how to achieve this ?

Comment: Should the other items be shown when a new sort query is entered? What is this new query, is it only a Boolean or is it string based sort?

Comment: yes other item should be shown below , only boolean

Answer (score 0):

Make adapter with multiple view holder and bind specific layout as first as your condition
[multiple item recyclerview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVJpWSalzbo)

Comment: I have singel api response from that response which ever item flag I get true that need to shown on top and rest below

Comment: how to filter out that particular card view the one with boolean true and show on top

Answer (score 0):

Add the method inside the adaptre, hope it helps:

```
 public void sortItem() {
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Item top =null ;
    for(Item item : data){
        if(!item.isTop){
            items.add(item);
        }else{
            top = item;
        }
    }
    if(top!=null){
       items.add(0, top);
    }
    data.clear();
    data.addAll(items);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}





 class Item{

     public Boolean isTop; 

  }
```

if You want get sorted list right away You can sort the list and submit yo recycler view adaper inside the activity:

```
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        Item top =null ;
        for(Item item : data){
            if(!item.isTop){
                items.add(item);
            }else{
                top = item;
            }
        }
        if(top!=null){
           items.add(0, top);
        }
  yourAdapter.submitList(items)
```

Comment: where to call sort item method in adapter in bindView holder?

Comment: @hema if you want get sorted list you can sort the list and submit yo recycler view adaper

Comment: @hema check my answer again. I have expanded the answer.